# detail of communicating server and client

Tags: web-services, wcf, client-server

I want to know how server and client communicate with each other.

How the client knows about the services or methods that server will provides for client? What is serialize class? Why we should use it? After that, what is wcf and why we should use it?

I really need this information.

Comment: Can you be more clear? Why should a client "know" about the services a server provide?

Comment: for example client wants to add two number...it isn't necessary to know server do this or not?if the client wants to know the methods that server has is there any way?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [WSDL](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_wsdl.asp)?

Comment: @NicoHaase no I don't know what is this. but I will search it. it is useful to finding the answer??

Comment: I don't know, as you have not yet clarified your question such that one could guess what you are looking for

Comment: I searched wsdl and find out that is what I want.but I have a question... server send this file to client ? to inform client from services of server ?